# How to select n numbers around the mean?

Tags: subset

I'm wondering if there is a way to select, say 5 values, around the mean of a series of numbers.

Below, there is an example of a series of numbers from 1:100 showing that I'm able to get the 5 top or last numbers from the series.

```
x = 1:100
y = 1:100
df = data.frame(x,y)
mean(df$x)

library(dplyr)

df %>% top_n(5, x)

df %>% top_n(-5, x)
```

In the end, I want 5 values that are situated around the mean of 50.5. For example, these numbers could be from 48,49, 50, 51, and 52.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df$z <- abs(df$x - mean(df$x))
arrange(df, z)$x[1:5]
```

This would get you the desired result!